# Why are different results when I call these functions?

Tags: javascript

I used many times JAVA but never used Javascript before. I try to learn about it, and now I have a problem with these functions. Same function with different results. The only difference between the functions this row:  `return joe;`

In `"rowSearch()"` function this code is outside of "loop", and in the `"rowSearch2()"` this code is inside of "loop".

If I call rowSearch2() then JOE variable has return value everytime, but when I call rowSearch() function sometimes there is no any return value. Maybe I missed or I do wrong something but I cant see that.

Thank you so much.

```
function rowSearch() {
  var index, table = document.getElementById('table');
  var joe = 1;
  joe = 1;
  var temp = '';
  var temp2 = '';
  for (var j = 1; j < table.rows.length + 1; j++) {
    temp = table.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML;
    temp2 = document.getElementById('srch').value;

    if (temp == temp2) {
      j = table.rows.length + 1;
      joe = 0;
    }
  }
  return joe;
}

function rowSearch2() {
  var index, table = document.getElementById('table');
  var joe = 1;
  joe = 1;
  var temp = '';
  var temp2 = '';
  for (var j = 1; j < table.rows.length + 1; j++) {
    temp = table.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML;
    temp2 = document.getElementById('srch').value;

    if (temp == temp2) {
      j = table.rows.length + 1;
      joe = 0;
    }

    return joe;
  }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script>

          function rowSearch() {
  var index, table = document.getElementById('table');
  var joe = 1;
  joe = 1;
  var temp = '';
  var temp2 = '';
  for (var j = 1; j < table.rows.length + 1; j++) {
    temp = table.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML;
    temp2 = document.getElementById('srch').value;

    if (temp == temp2) {
      j = table.rows.length + 1;
      joe = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('demo4').innerHTML=joe;
  }

}
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        Data: <input type="text" name="srch" id="srch" /><br/><br/>
        <button onclick="rowSearch();">Check</button><br/><br/>

        <table id="table" border="1">

            <tr>
                <th>Data</th>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data1</td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data2</td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <<td>Data3</td>


            </tr>



        </table>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="demo2"></p>
        <p id="demo3"></p>
        <p id="demo4"></p>

 </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I would like to find a value(srch input) in the table. If it is in the table, then I will call a function with value of JOE, else call a different function.

Comment: Can you add the corresponding HTML script also and make a snippet so that it will be easy to debug?

Comment: `return` in loops will terminate it. So, your `rowSearch2()` will terminate loop after one iteration and send the value of `joe` to calling function. In your first function `rowSearch()`, you are allowing to complete for loop and then send the value of `joe` to calling function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @randomSoul already mentioned, the two functions are not equal, but as far as I remember, JAVA does behave the same here.

A `return` statement somewhere inside a function immediately stops the function and returns a value; even inside a loop.

So, your two functions as pseudo-code

```
function rowSearch() {
  if the `innerHTML` of the first cell in **any row (except the first)** of the table equals `srch`
  then return 0 
  else return 1
}
```

*I'd assume that the first row is your table header*

and

```
function rowSearch2() {
  if the table has at least two rows
  then if the `innerHTML` of the first cell in **the second row** of the table equals `srch`
    then return 0 
    else return 1
  else return undefined
}
```

The only difference between JS and Java here is the that in JS `rowSearch2` will implicitely `return undefined` when there are no rows, whereas Java will throw an Error. 
Or maybe not even compile, because not every path of the function returns a value. *Java doesn't like such ambiguity ;)*

Comment: Yes the two functions are not the same and also you can remove `//joe = 1;` as you are already initializing `var joe =1`.. not that it might have any effect on your execution